# Image preview in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, image, air, preview

I am working on an image management application. We have an Adobe AIR client talking to a WAMP server. The MySQL DB stores the images as blobs.
We have an image search feature. Upon searching, I am displaying the results as XMLList in a popup window and provided a download button. Downloads work fine. I also want to add a preview button to the popup.
Please let me know how can I code this. Without having the file on the client, I cannot preview. But when I use save() method, the os dialog opens up. Anything to be done on the PHP side?
Please help.

Regards
Jad.

Comment: Is your plan to generate a persistent thumbnail to store in your DB, or do you want to generate the thumbnail on the fly?

Comment: Hi Jon, I just want to show the preview of the image file at the client. I already have the "download" option to download the image file. Wanted to add the preview button also.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean to display an Image? Wouldn't the normal  work? Of course, for performance issues, your PHP code must render smaller images (thumbnails).

Correct me if wrongly understood your question. :(